# Inaccuracies w/ prcomp? R lang PCA for eigenfaces

Tags: r, pca, svd, eigenvector

My question is: in the case of having a matrix we want to do PCA on, where the number of features greatly outnumbers the number of trials, why doesn't prcomp behave as expected (or am I missing something)?

Below is a summary of the issue, [full code is here](https://gist.github.com/ilyakava/88bbb193bf57ffe4eac4), [compressed 7MB data source is here](http://cl.ly/2Z2i0q0Q261E) (is 55MB uncompressed), [target image is here](http://cl.ly/430x441c1h24).

My exact situation is that I have a matrix p by n matrix X (p = features, n = trials) where the trials are photos taken of faces, and the features are the pixels in the photos (so a 32256 by 148 matrix). What I want to do is find the principal component score vectors of that matrix. Since finding the covariance matrix XX^T is too expensive, an easy solution is to find the eigenvectors (v_i) of X^TX and transform them by X (Xv_i) [more info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenface#Computing_the_eigenvectors).

```
XTX <- t(X) %*% X # missing the 1 / n - 1 for cov matrix b/c we normalize later anyway
eigen <- eigen(XTX)
eigenvectors.XTX.col <- eigen$vectors

principal.component.scores <- apply(eigenvectors.XTX.col, 2, function(c) {
  normalize.vector(X %*% matrix(c, ncol = 1))
})
```

The principal component scores are eigenfaces in my case, and can be used to successfully reconstruct the target face as seen here: http://cl.ly/image/260w0N0u0Z3y (refer to my [full code for how](https://gist.github.com/ilyakava/88bbb193bf57ffe4eac4))

Passing X to prcomp should do something equivalent, but has a different result than the above homegrown way:

```
pca <- prcomp(X)
pca$x # right size, but wrong pc scores
```

The result of using `pca$x` in reconstructing the face is not total crap, but much worse: http://cl.ly/image/2p19360u2P43

I also checked that using `prcomp` on `t(x)` yielded a different rotation matrix, so `prcomp` is doing something fancy, but something mysterious under the hood. I know from [here](http://psych.colorado.edu/wiki/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=labs:learnr:emily_-_principal_components_analysis_in_r:pca_how_to.pdf) that `prcomp` is using SVD to calculate the principal component loading vectors instead of eigen decomposition, but that should not be leading to any errors here (or so I think...).

What is the correct way of using the built in prcomp method, there must be a way, right?

Comment: Due to "maths", the method can not solve your problem. You should have at least as many observations as variables, but preferably more of the former.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @RomanLuštrik! [This source](http://psych.colorado.edu/wiki/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=labs:learnr:emily_-_principal_components_analysis_in_r:pca_how_to.pdf) corroborates what you said for the method `princomp`, but as I was surprised to find in the answer below, it is not the case that you need more observations than variables (this would be impossible in some disciplines like genomics, or even here with facial recognition). Rather the issue here is some annoying defaults in `prcomp` as well as a lack of normalization. Sorry for the lame problem in my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, the answer is not a fun one at all, and rather has to do with default parameters in the `prcomp` method:

To solve this issue, first, I looked at [the R source of prcomp](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/da62cf194897d5fe035affa6f88d96f36a18fcda/src/library/stats/R/prcomp.R#L42) and saw that the rotation matrix should equal `svd(X)$v`. Checking this on the R command line proved that with my X ([data here](http://cl.ly/2Z2i0q0Q261E)) it did not. This is because even though there is the default param `scale = F` to `prcomp`, prcomp will still run the R `scale` method, if only to center the matrix, which is default True as seen [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/da62cf194897d5fe035affa6f88d96f36a18fcda/src/library/stats/R/prcomp.R#L22). In my case, this is bad because I passed the data as already centered (subtracted mean image).

So, rerunning with `prcomp(X, center = F)` will yield a rotation matrix equal to `svd(X)$v` as expected. From this point forward, the only "mistake" `prcomp` makes when constructing `prcomp(X, center = F)$x` will be to not normalize the columns, so they are each only off by a scalar multiple from the `principal.component.scores` matrix I reference above in my code. Without normalizing `prcomp(X, center = F)$x` the results are better, but not quite great as seen here:
http://cl.ly/image/3u2y3m1h2S0o

But after normalizing via `pca.x.norm <- apply(pca$x, 2, normalize.vector)` the results of `prcomp` in reconstructing the face is identical: 
http://cl.ly/image/24390O3x0A0x

tl;dr - `prcomp` unexpectedly centers the data even with the param `scale = F`, plus for the purposes of eigenfaces you will need to normalize the columns of `prcomp(X, center = F)$x`, then everything will work as desired!